# Not able to connect RoboMongo with Amazon instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I'm not able to connect RoboMongo with Amazon instance.
Tried this http://blog.mongohq.com/robomongo-your-next-shell/

Opened inbound port in the instance. Still no Luck. Anyone have done this?

Edited:

[image]

After I press test or connect it goes on and seems it's trying to connect but after a while a message pops up saying unable to connect with mongodb.

Edit

by setting the host as 'localhost' worked.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You're not giving us much to work with. Are you getting some error?

Comment: Have you opened the port in your security group as well?

Comment: Have you tried connecting via `ssh` with the same credentials? On the Robomongo `Connection` tab, have you set hostname to "localhost"? I would try logging in with `ssh`, then use the same details as the `Connection` tab to make sure this connects, eg:  `mongo localhost:27017`.

Comment: @Stennie spot on. Putting localhost worked. thanks a lot.

Comment: Please don't add "resolved", or variations thereof, to the title of your question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86278/detect-edits-to-add-solved-or-resolved-to-the-title-and-direct-the-user-to-a.

Answer (score 4):

From @Stennie

"Have you tried connecting via ssh with the same credentials? On the Robomongo Connection tab, have you set hostname to "localhost"? I would try logging in with ssh, then use the same details as the Connection tab to make sure this connects, eg:  mongo localhost:27017."