# How to connect aws VM running mongo DB to robomongo on windows machine?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, robo3t

I am trying to access my mongodb databases which are running on VM on amazonaws. I am trying to connect through robomongo. Getting can not connect.

I have checked that mongoDB listening to 27017 and commented bind_ip = 0.0.0.0 to #bind_ip = 0.0.0.0 in mongodb.conf in /etc/mongodb.conf

Comment: Are u trying to connect with SSH? Need more info, can you post a snapshot of how you are trying to connect.

Comment: On aws VM i am connecting with SSH. And with robomongo i am trying to connect aws VM but showing Unable to connect to mongoDB

Comment: Looks similar to this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392320/not-able-to-connect-robomongo-with-amazon-instance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your [MongoDB version pre-3.0](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#mongodb-cr-authentication), so your MongoDB uses `MONGODB-CR Authentication` then you can use Robomongo today. Otherwise RoboMongo cannot be used yet. (2015-05-16)
Because MongoDB 3.0 uses [SCRAM-SHA-1](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#scram-sha-1-and-existing-user-credentials) credentials.
(https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/766)

### To Connect MongoDB 2.6 and Earlier Versions Using Robomongo Directives;

1. Open mongod.conf file using `sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf` command. Then mark as comment line port line like the following;

   `# port = 27017`

   Use `CTRL + X` to save file and exit.
2. Create a user that will be used on RoboMongo

   db.createUser({ user: "admin", pwd: "GiveASecretPassword", roles: [{ role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" }, { role: "readWrite", db: "config" }]})
3. Allow port 27017 on Security Groups page on your EC2 console.

[image]

4. Create a new connection on RoboMongo

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Comment bindip in /etc/mongod.conf
2. Find ip address of your vm
3. Open custom TCP rule in AWS to listen to port 27017

Note:
Requires only IP address & port to connect to mongodb. (Use connection tab in robomongo)